# Extract values in name=value lines with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm really sorry for asking because there are some questions like this around. But can't get the answer fixed to make problem.

This are the input lines (e.g. from a config file)

```
profile2.name=share2
profile8.name=share8
profile4.name=shareSSH
profile9.name=share9
```

I just want to extract the values behind the `=` sign with *Python 3.9. regex*.

I tried this on [regex101](https://regex101.com).

```
^profile[0-9]\.name=(.*?)
```

But this gives me the variable name including the `=` sign as result; e.g. `profile2.name=`. But I want exactly the inverted opposite.

The expected results (what Pythons `re.find_all()` return) are

```
['share2', 'share8', 'shareSSH', 'share9']
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems this does't work. https://regex101.com/r/T0hliX/1 Maybe a dialect problem?

Comment: But what doesn't work? It is matching `profile<digits>.name` in every case. What are you expected matches?

Comment: I updated my question. I am not interested in the match. I want to get the string behind the match as a result.

Comment: Just `^profile[0-9]+\.name=(.+)` in `re.findall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pattern `profile\d+\.name=(.*)`, look at [Regex 101 example](https://regex101.com/r/fngO4k/1)

```py
import re
re.findall('profile\d+\.name=(.*)', txt)
# output 
['share2', 'share8', 'shareSSH', 'share9']
```

But this problem doesn't necessarily need regex, split should work absolutely fine:

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ? quantifier. It will make your capture group match an empty st
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZbsdH6/1)